# CSS - Dynamic width for horizontal list (in a list of a list of a list)

Tags: css, dynamic, width

i am trying to achieve this layout:

[image: thumbnail layout]

The nearest I can get is this:

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
.project_thumbnail_info {
  margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.project_thumbnail_info li {
  margin: 0 15px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  clear: right;
}

.project_thumbnail_info li ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}

.project_thumbnail_info li ul li {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

.project_thumbnail_info_avatar {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
}

.project_thumbnail_info_hashtags li {
  float: left!important;
  clear: right!important;
  padding: 0px 8px 0px 0px;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h2 a {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-md-6">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" class="img-responsive" />
  <ul class="project_thumbnail_info">
    <li class="project_thumbnail_info_avatar">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/" class="img-responsive">
    </li>
    <li class="project_thumbnail_info_detail">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <h2><a href="#">dem hinterfragen</a></h2>
        </li>
        <li>
          <ul class="project_thumbnail_info_hashtags">
            <li>
              <a href="#">#hashtag</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">#hashtag</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">#hashtag</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">#hashtag</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">#hashtag</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The problem is, in case the column get smaller (or more hashtags are added), the title and hashtags are jumping down, because there is no room left. This isnt what I want, but I cant find any solution.

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `display:flex` to achieve what you want.

I have removed all your floats and changed the for inline-block (hashtags) and flex (main ul container)

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
.project_thumbnail_info {
  margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.project_thumbnail_info_detail {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.project_thumbnail_info li {
  margin: 0 15px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.project_thumbnail_info li ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.project_thumbnail_info_avatar {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
}

.project_thumbnail_info_hashtags li {
  padding: 0px 8px 0px 0px;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h2 a {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-md-6">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" class="img-responsive" />
  <ul class="project_thumbnail_info">
    <li class="project_thumbnail_info_avatar">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/" class="img-responsive">
    </li>
    <li class="project_thumbnail_info_detail">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <h2><a href="#">dem hinterfragen</a></h2>
        </li>
        <li>
          <ul class="project_thumbnail_info_hashtags">
            <li>
              <a href="#">#hashtag</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">#hashtag</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">#hashtag</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">#hashtag</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">#hashtag</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped. 
Didn't know the flex rule and after adding your solution line by line I get a clue.

Comment: Here's a couple of useful links to learn about flex: [A complete guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and [Flex playground](http://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/adLPwv). It's good to learn as bootstrap are moving to it and also it allows for all the best bits of tables and floats without all the bad bits

Answer (score 0):

Please find the solution

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
.project_thumbnail_info {
  margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.project_thumbnail_info_detail
{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70%;
 }
.project_thumbnail_info li {
  margin: 0 15px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  clear: right;
 }

.project_thumbnail_info li ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}

.project_thumbnail_info li ul li {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

.project_thumbnail_info_avatar {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
}

.project_thumbnail_info_hashtags li {
  float: left!important;
  clear: right!important;
  padding: 0px 8px 0px 0px;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h2 a {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-md-6">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" class="img-responsive" />
  <ul class="project_thumbnail_info">
    <li class="project_thumbnail_info_avatar">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/" class="img-responsive">
    </li>
    <li class="project_thumbnail_info_detail">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <h2><a href="#">dem hinterfragen</a></h2>
        </li>
        <li>
          <ul class="project_thumbnail_info_hashtags">
            <li>
              <a href="#">#hashtag</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">#hashtag</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">#hashtag</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">#hashtag</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">#hashtag</a>
            </li>
             <li>
              <a href="#">#hashtag</a>
            </li>
             <li>
              <a href="#">#hashtag</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```